# Allauth, redirect to external url after email confirmation

Tags: django-allauth

I configured my allauth signup and email confirmation. I am able to receive the email confirmation and click verify email but I wanted it to redirect to an external URL which is the main frontend URL. So instead of `/account/profile` it should redirect to `https://redirect-to-here.com` I tried using the redirect shortcut from django but can't seem to make it work also I'm trying to read the documentation on how to achieve this.

```
    def get_email_confirmation_redirect_url(self, request):
    return resolve("auth_redirect")

    # url
    path("auth/redirect/", auth_direct, name="auth_redirect")

    # method
    def auth_redirect():
       return redirect("https://redirect-to-here.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.py`, set this variable

```py
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = "https://redirect-to-here.com"
```